# Decoy choices in matching question using examdesign

Tags: examdesign

I'm using the examdesign template to create an exam for my students.  I want to place extra choices in the matching section (i.e. decoys), but cannot figure out how, nor can I find any solution online.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
\begin{matching}[title={Matching}]
Match the following definitions with the listed terms.
\pair{Elvis Costello}{Spike}
\pair{Nirvana}{Nevermind}
%But how do I add "The Wall" as another choice?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a sleepy mind can do.

```
\documentclass{examdesign}
\Fullpages

\makeatletter
\def\dpair#1{%
    \expandafter
  \xdef\csname sec\thesection @\thequestion @tag\endcsname{\thetemp}
  \expandafter
  \gdef\csname sec\thesection @qst\thequestion\endcsname{%
    \exam@PairA{\item[]\hskip-\leftmargin
      \ifanswer
      \makebox[\exam@MatchingLineLength][c]{\exam@GetMatchingAnswer}%
      \hskip\exam@MatchingLineAfterSkip
      \else
      \rule{\exam@MatchingLineLength}{0pt}%
      \hskip\exam@MatchingLineAfterSkip
      \fi}}
%        \stepcounter{question}
  \expandafter
  \xdef\csname sec\thesection @\thequestion @tag\endcsname{\thetemp}
  \expandafter
  \gdef\csname sec\thesection @qst\thequestion\endcsname{%
    \exam@PairB{\item\relax\exam@SaveMatchingAnswer #1}}
  \stepcounter{temp}
  \stepcounter{question}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{matching}[title={Matching}]
Match the following definitions with the listed terms.
\pair{Elvis Costello}{Spike}
\pair{Nirvana}{Nevermind}
\dpair{The wall}   %% don't use \dpair at the beginning but only at the end
\dpair{Rahul Dravid}   %% nick named The Wall
\end{matching}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This can be improved further but now time to sleep.